# Problem showing error messages on validation using Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

Why won't error message display with the code below?

I can see the error message in page source code though.

```
@if($errors->has('slug'))
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
  <strong>{{ $errors->first('slug')}}</strong>
</span>
@endif
```

However this works:

```
@if($errors->has('slug'))
<p>{{ $errors->first('slug')}}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Does `class="invalid-feedback"` have some logic to only show up in some cases? Check your `css` or `js` for that class.

Comment: Please show your class 'invalid-feedback'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class "invalid-feedback" has display none in bootstrap 4.
You can add the class "d-block" to display it "invalid-feedback d-block"